# Complex numbers property proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I eas given this quesstion in one of my Linear Algebra course with the excercises regarding minimal polynomialsm eigenvalues and diagonalizable matrix:
Show that for any two numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ exist $c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $c+d=a$ and $cd=b$.
I have no idea if and how it's related to the material we just covered, and have no clue how to attack it. I tried prooving it straight forward algebrically, but it's just got messy.
Any hints? clues? ideas?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Think about the roots of $x^2 - ax + b$.